# Is the Large Number Hypothesis still a subject worth researching?

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, cosmology, standard-model

I've done some research on it for an [essay competition of the Gravity research Foundation](https://www.academia.edu/36109148/Electron_Mass_in_Gravitation_and_Cosmology) and shared it with other physicists but the response was very dismal in the sense that most physicists didn't seem to care much for the topic but seemed to like my work. Is the Large Number Hypothesis old news?

Answer (score 2):

"Is X worth researching?" will always be somewhat subjective. The LNH is in many ways an old hypothesis that has so far not panned out into anything really useful or exciting (as far as I know), so I can understand that most physicists don't jump with excitement about the topic. It is a fairly fringe topic (although not as far out as Eddington's fundamental theory, which in some sense is a parent of the hypothesis).

Still, the "[naturalness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalness_(physics))" is the modern incarnation (minus the time-varying constants of nature) and is regarded as an important issue. Explaining the cosmological constant magnitude is regarded as relevant. However, many of the approaches (like anthropics) tend to rub physicists the wrong way - there is a fair bit of philosophical discussion about what kinds of explanations of theories are even admissible here. This tend to produce even more heat than light.